# Select last li within ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to select every last li within each row.

I have a ul with 6 list items which have been styled to have 3 rows and two columns. I need to be able to select the last item of each row to reset margins.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/162/

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [CSS3 `:nth-child()` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp). As CSS3 might not be compatible with all browsers, also consider [jQuery's :nth-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: CSS3 is not widely supported yet I need to stick to a jquery or javascript solution - thanks anyway

Comment: In fact, jQuery polyfills the `:nth-child()` selector **because of** suboptimal support, and it works identically to the CSS version.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the line of:

```
$('ul#some-id li:last-child');
```

EDIT: So if I understand correctly from the comment in your jsfiddle, you'd like to get the second, fourth and sixth li of the list?

If yes, try

```
$('ul li:nth-child(even)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/164/

Comment: This will only select the very last item of the list - not what I'm after sorry

Comment: Your question says to select the last li. Maybe you need to edit it.

Comment: $('ul li:nth-child(even)'); Is what I am after - works a charm! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("li:odd").css("margin-right", "0");
});​
```

this works

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery, use `:odd` selector (note it's zero-based, that's why it's not `:even`).

The CSS version of it is `:nth-child(even)` (one based, that's why it's not `odd`), as in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/167/

The jQuery version is `:odd`, as in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvBqA/171/